# laravel-graphql php artisan command 'Could not open input file: make:graphql:type'

Tags: php, laravel, graphql

l have been at the laravel project folder. of course, l can run other `php artisan` command.

Here is my command line:

```
$ php7 artisan
Laravel Framework 5.7.9

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]
 ...

 make
  ....
  make:graphql:mutation  Create a new GraphQL mutation class
  make:graphql:query     Create a new GraphQL query class
  make:graphql:type      Create a new GraphQL type class
  ... // other command hide here

$ php7 make:graphql:type Meta
Could not open input file: make:graphql:type
```

l'm sure l was under the laravel project, and other artisan command could work

l installed laravel-graphql with composer `composer7 require 'folklore/graphql'` with version 1.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to include the artisan command in your input

```
php artisan make:graphql:type Meta
```